# Using ng-repeat how do I remove the empty UL from the dom

Tags: angularjs

I'm using a simple ng-repeat to create a filtered input that allows you to filter a list of schools.

I would like the UL to be removed from the DOM when there are no suitable results (i.e. any li's).

Example: DOM

```
<ul id="filter_quickfind" data-ng-show="query" class="dropdown-menu">
   <!-- ngRepeat: school in schools | filter: query -->
</ul>
```

My Code:

```
<input id="input_quickfind" ng-model="query" placeholder="Find a school" class="form-control" autofocus>

    <ul id="filter_quickfind" data-ng-show="query" class="dropdown-menu">
      <li data-ng-repeat="school in schools | filter: query">
        <a href="views/profile.html">{{school.name}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

I've seen a solution on stack overflow that comes close but I couldn't relate it to my code.  If anyone can help that would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think u need introduce additional array, say filteredSchools, filter it on input ng-change, then u can use ng-if. You can wrap it to simple directive ofc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `ng-if` on the length of the `schools` array:

```
<ul id="filter_quickfind" data-ng-show="query" class="dropdown-menu" ng-if="schools.length">
```

Comment: Okay, looks promising, only problem is it hides all results.  I've tried ng-if="!!schools.length" and ng-if="!schools.length" but they also don't give the desired result.

Comment: @ShannaBarnard it's not hiding the results. `ng-if` creates an isolated scope. You have to reference the parent scope in `ng-repeat` like this `school in $parent.schools`

Comment: you hide element if schools is empty, not schools | filter: query

Comment: @ShannaBarnard it does not work when you do `schools.length` because that is your original list, i believe you want to hide when the  filter result returns nothing. they both are different lists. What you can do is on ng-change set the schools from the controller applying the filter, keep the original school list separately. And just use the filtered list for ng-if and ng-repeat

Comment: @MathewFoscarini it does not create any isolated scope, instead it creates a child scope and that does not seem to be an issue here, because schools is going to be available on the scope of ul.